# A question about abounds with recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I need to prove that for the recurrence relation $a_n = 2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ for a big enough n $(2\frac{1}{3})^n\le a_n \le (2\frac{1}{2})^n$.

I managed to prove $(5)^{\frac{n}{2}}\le a_n \le (2\frac{1}{2})^n$ but the lower bound doesn't get right.

I used that $a_{n-1} = 2a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$ so $2a_{n-2} \le a_{n-1}$ for the upper bound and lower bound.

Comment: The general solution is of the form $a_n = A(\sqrt{2}+1)^n + B(\sqrt{2}-1)^n$, with $A, B$ constants, that can be determined from two initial values of $a_n$.

Comment: @Muralidharan I believe this should be $a_n = A(1+\sqrt{2})^n + B(1-\sqrt{2})^n$.

Comment: @CyeWaldman, Yes, Thanks, it should be $a_n = A(1+\sqrt{2})^n + B(1-\sqrt{2})^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Lower bound can be proven by induction

$\displaystyle a_{n+1}=2a_{n}+a_{n-1}\ge \frac{2^n}{3^n}+\frac{2^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}\ge \frac{2^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}\underbrace{\left(\frac 32+\frac 94\right)}_{>1}\ge\frac{2^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}$

But for upper bound $(2\frac 12)^n=1$ this is wrong because $a_0=1$ is forced  since $(\frac 23)^0\le a_0\le(\frac 22)^0$

Also $a_n>0$ from condition $a_n\ge (\frac 23)^n$ so it is easy to see that $a_2=2a_1+a_0>a_0$ and all $a_{2n}>a_0$ in the same way. So this upper bound cannot stand.

Continuing Muralidharan argument we can prove that : $a_n=A(1+\sqrt 2)^n+B(1-\sqrt 2)^n$

Since $|1-\sqrt 2|<1$ then $(1-\sqrt 2)^n\to 0$ so if $A\ne 0$ then $a_n\to\infty$.

If we want to keep $a_n$ bounded then $A=0$.

Thus $a_n=B(1-\sqrt 2)^n$ which is changing sign every $n$, so lower bound is not satisfied.

Either way, there is something wrong in your inequality statement.

Comment: It is not $(\frac{2}{3})^n$ . It's actually $(\frac{7}{3})^n$. You probably misunderstood.